# Pop gets stuck in one screen and throws an error

Tags: flutter

in my application I have a sequence of screens that after their use should return to the first one, I'm using a counter to keep how many times I should pop, but for some reason it doesn't pop all the way through and gets stuck at the first screen of the sequence and throws this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (19475): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
```

This is the method I'm using to pop

```
  void closeAction() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.backTimes);
  }
```

I've tried setting the value manually but the error still persists so I think the method is ok.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Dialog box that for some reason caused the error, just removed it.